Creating a cycle in Airflow DAG
I want to create a workflow with the below flow:

trigger a Glue job
If the glue job fails, I want to trigger a lambda which does some logic to help with glue
wait or sleep
Re-trigger the glue job

Since 1 and 4 are the same step, Airflow detects it as a cycle and does not let me run it. How do I achieve my workflow using Airflow ?
